# Mix-blend-mode not working on Chrome but works as expected in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I know a transparent background in Chrome cannot be animated with mix-blend-mode, but my background-color is set to rgba(0,0,0,0.1) and the effect still isn't working in Chrome.

```
nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding-top: 100px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;

  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    
    li {
      margin: 0 30px;
      
      a {
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
        color: red;
        text-decoration: none;
        
        &:before {
          content: '';
          z-index: -1;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
          height: 0px;
          width: 0px;
          border-radius: 100px;
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
          transition: 0.25s ease all;
        }
        
        &:hover {
          color: #000;

          &:before {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: red;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p2134Lde/1/

Comment: I'd like you to review your title: "Mix-blend-mode not working on **Chrome** but works as expected in Firefox **and Chrome**"

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's due to the use of the big negative z-index. Remove it and make sure you have positive z-index for element that need to be above it. Also make sure to set background to html and body.

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background:#fff;
}
html {
  background:#fff;
}

.wave {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.wave svg {
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding-top: 100px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul li {
  margin: 0 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul li a {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  color: tomato;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: 0.25s ease all;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
nav ul li a:hover:before {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="wave">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 414 124" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 87L9 74C17 62 35 37 52 27C69 17 86 21 104 27C121 33 138 41 155 37C173 33 190 17 207 27C224 37 242 54 259 54C276 54 293 37 311 27C328 17 345 33 362 54C380 74 397 99 405 112L414 124V0H405C397 0 380 0 362 0C345 0 328 0 311 0C293 0 276 0 259 0C242 0 224 0 207 0C190 0 173 0 155 0C138 0 121 0 104 0C86 0 69 0 52 0C35 0 17 0 9 0H0V87Z" fill="#FA8072"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```